# I have generated the bundle.js with webpack, but my React App continue using /static/bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, webpack-4

I am generating the .js and .js.gz in the /dist folder, but really I need that this files will be in the /build/static/js

When I upload to production my react app, the only files that I upload to the server is the build folder, so the webpack generated files aren't taken in consideration.

This is the .js file that use my app when is running (/static/js/) and not the webpack generated.

[image]

Do you know how could I force to webpack to create the .js and .js.gz files inside the /build folder?

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
     new CompressionPlugin({
     algorithm: 'gzip',
     test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
     threshold: 10240,
     minRatio: 0.8
     })
    ]

}
```

And this is the script section in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bundled files will be going to the path mentioned to the **output** variable.

Change this line from: path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
to: path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/static/js')

Comment: And how can I run the app and ensure that is using the bundle that is generated by webpack?

Comment: Your scripts have all the required commands. Use npm run dev for your scripts configurations to bundle the webpack and then use npm start. You can see all your bundled files by webpack in the sources tab in the chrome developer console

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that, If you have both versions of the file:

main.js
main.js.gz

The browser ask by the gzip version and the server send only the gzip one, But you have to have the two versions!

thanks!